# What category does "broken English" fall into?

Tags: english, pidgins

So I've been reading for about two hours now about pidgins and creoles. Can broken English such as *Engrish* be considered a pidgin? Or do they fall into another category?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken English"? I doubt it's used to consistently refer to anything that could be so easily categorised.

Comment: _Broken English_ is just a putdown for how other people talk. Pidgins may use English words (many do; they're useful and they're there) or not, and when they do, they always change something about the words and how they're used, just like any borrowing. English borrowed thousands of words from French, but we don't think of ourselves as speaking "Broken French", do we?

Answer (score 1):

The only case that I know of where "broken English" is a pidgin is Nigerian or Cameroonian Pidgin, which is called "Broken" by some. Otherwise, it is simply English as a second language, with a low level of proficiency (or emulation of such English by a native speaker of English). It is an individual phenomenon, where a person learns (and uses) some English but not a lot, but pidgin is where two (or more) societies meet, have to communicate but don't have a common language – it's a social phenomenon.

Comment: I challenge the notion "is is simply English as a second language, with a low level of proficiency" because of the phenomenon known as [foreigner talk](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/foreigner-talk),–But I don't know a cromulent category comprising things like "foreigner talk", "baby talk" etc.

Comment: Call them what they are; ignorant descriptive terms. We don't have to categorize them, any more than we do any other nonsense.